# $datetostring in mongo does not work

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have a question that has made me busy for 3 days and still fighting with it: I have mongodb query as follow:

```
 db.test.aggregate([ 
  { 
     $project: { 
         yearMonthDay: { 
              $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } 
         } 
     } 
  } 
])
```

now I am trying to convert it to java but I really do not know how to convert this line:

```
yearMonthDay: { 
       $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } 
}
```

I tried this code but not working at all:

```
 DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
 DBObject format = new BasicDBObject("format","%Y-%m-%d");
 format.put("date", "$date");
 DBObject formattedDate = new BasicDBObject("$dateToString",format);
 project.put("yearMonthDay",formattedDate);
```

but I get the following error:

> com.mongodb.CommandFailureException:
>
> { "serverUsed" : "...." , "errmsg" : "exception: invalid
>   operator '$dateToString'" , "code" : 15999 , "ok" : 0.0}

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  `$dateToString` was added in 3.0.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yes I am using version 3

Answer (score 1):

I inserted a sample data in collection.

```
 {
   "_id" : 1,
   "item" : "abc",
   "price" : 10,
   "quantity" : 2,
   "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:15:39.736Z")
 }
```

I am able to get the desired output for your aggregation query using this java code:

```
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject();
    DBObject format = new BasicDBObject("format", "%Y-%m-%d");
    format.put("date", "$date");
    DBObject formattedDate = new BasicDBObject("$dateToString", format);
    project.put("yearMonthDay", formattedDate);
    DBObject aggregate = new BasicDBObject("$project", project);

    List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(aggregate);
    AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
    for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

For more details on Java Driver and Aggregation, please find : http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/

Comment: Thank u ... that is strange because I use you code and I get this error :Command failed with error 15999: 'exception: invalid operator '$dateToString''... also I use this dependency from maven http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.0.0-beta3  Are you using the same ?

Comment: I am also using the same 3.0.0-beta3 version.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the same error when I am running mongoDB 2.6 server. Please make sure you are running an instance of 3.0 server.

Comment: Not really even when I use version 3 I get that error :(

Comment: for both server and jar?